# How to get data attribute of clicked link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I have the following event listener - how can I get the value of the data attribute of the clicked link. The console give me undefined in the example below?

```
 var removeLink = Dropzone.createElement("<a class='dz-remove' href='javascript:undefined;' data-file-id='2' >Remove file</a>");

 removeLink.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      var a = $(this);

      console.log(a.attr("data-file-id"));
 });
```

I can get it to work if I use the following syntax but I need to use the arrow function so that I can access some other properties:

```
removeLink.addEventListener("click", function (e) { ...});
```

I've tried the following but that get some other id altogether:

```
 var a = $(e.currentTarget); 

 console.log(a.attr("data-file-id"));
```

Comment: @Huangism not a duplicate why have you down voted? I've clearly shown what I've tried and it doesnt work - What I've tried is the same as whats in your linked questions and it doesnt work.

Comment: @adam78 First I retracted the close vote after reading the question again, second I didn't down vote. You know what they say about assumptions

Comment: @JJJ I've looked at the post and it doesnt provide the answer to my question. I've also updated my own post to reflect that.

Comment: @Huangism my apolgies. But I cant stand people downvoting without even attempting to answer the question and automatically assuming its a duplicate.

Comment: @adam78 See my answer as to what was wrong with your approach.

Comment: Yeah this is all duplicate.  First off you're using the Arrow Function which does not have a *this* context so `var a = $(this);` does not do at all what you think it does, the duplicate link answer explains this.  As for accessing a data attribute, there are already answers on SO doing this via pure JS and jQuery.  Nothing in this question is original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **[`createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)** doesn't work that way. If you want to create a node using a string, use `innerHTML` or **[`insertadjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)**
2. Instead of `this`, use [**`e.target`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)
3. `.attr()` as a JavaScript method is deprecated, use **[`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)** instead.

```js
 document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "<a class='dz-remove' href='javascript:undefined;' data-file-id='2' >Remove file</a>");
 
 var removeLink = document.querySelector('.dz-remove');

removeLink.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

  e.preventDefault();

  var tgt = e.target;

  e.stopPropagation();


  console.log(tgt.getAttribute('data-file-id'));
});
```

Comment: for `data-` attributes, the recommended practice is to use [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

Comment: @ErikPhilips Wasn't aware plain JavaScript finally has that method, thanks....just searched MDN... not there?

Comment: You should use `e.currentTarget`, not `e.target`.

Comment: If you clicked my link, it would have taken you to jQuery's website...

Comment: @ErikPhilips I think the recommended practice is to avoid jQuery when it is not necessary and just use [`tgt.dataset.fileId`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

Comment: @ErikPhilips I was being facetious, there's no `data()` method for plain JavaScript.

Comment: @Bergi the `e.currentTarget` and `e.target` are both `removeLink` in this case (unless I'm mistaken) Why would one be a better choice than the other?

Comment: @Bergi the following works fine `var id = e.target.getAttribute('data-file-id'); `  why use `e.currentTarget`?

Comment: @adam78 If the markup changed so that the link would e.g. contain a `<span>` or `<em>` tag, it would not work when you clicked on the inner element. If you want an alias for `this`, it's `e.currentTarget` not `e.target`.

Comment: @adam78 AFAIK `e.currentTarget` is the node registered to the event which in this case `removeLink`. `e.target` is the origin of the event more commonly referred to as the clicked element which in this case `removeLink`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
removeLink.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

      e.preventDefault();

      var target = e.currentTarget;

      e.stopPropagation();


      console.log(target.data('file-id'));
    });
```

Comment: You should use `e.currentTarget`, not `e.target`.